# Docker for MAC - force static IP

Tags: macos, docker, docker-for-mac

I'm using Docker for Mac (previously I was using Docker Tollbox on Windows) and I have problem - from to time to time Docker changes IP - so far it's using only IP 192.168.0.198 and 192.168.0.196

The question is - is it possible somehow to force Docker to use always same IP.

It's now very frustrating when I have set:

- hosts to this IP
- SSH to this IP
- database to this IP

and after some time it seems I need to switch it again to the other IP because Docker decided to use different IP. As far as I remember it never happened for me on Windows - Docker was using all the time same IP.

If you need anything more to add here please let me know.

Comment: that sounds like your local host ip, not the docker hypervisor ip (which doesn't normally matter, docker forwards ports from localhost to the docker VM automatically)

Comment: the solution would be to set a static IP in macOS: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25448

Comment: @avigil So you are telling me this IP is the IP assigned to my Mac machine by router and has nothing in common with Docker? If yes, you can add this as an answer. It was completely different IP on Windows (for sure that IP was not Windows machine IP) and that's why I was thinking this IP changing is connected to Docker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker for Mac provides a [networking layer](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/) that exposes your published docker ports on the host machine. If you are accessing a container from the same machine, you should be able to use `localhost` to access docker services. The example in the linked documentation uses nginx as an example:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
```

After running this you should see a page being served at http://localhost in your browser.

For accessing services outside the host machine you need to configure macOS to use a manually configured static address, as described at https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25448, or assign the machine a reserved address in the DHCP configuration for your router. Also check that you don't have any firewall restrictions that might block traffic. If everything is set up properly, you can just use the address for your Mac to access your containers. There is no need to use a special address.

Comment: As I already said in comment I was sure this IP is not from my local machine (on Windows it's not). So now I assigned static IP for my Mac on router and it should work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the subnet 192.168.0.x used by docker bridge or it is just a host network?. If it’s host network, then assign your host a static IP address instead of relying on DHCP server which can assign you a different IP address anytime.

If it’s a docker network, then give the network a static IP address. A comprehensive guide on Docker networking is on Aquasec [Docker containers](https://www.aquasec.com/wiki) Wiki page.